# Convert TimeStamp in TZ string format to TimeStamp in Oracle

Tags: oracle, timestamp, type-conversion

I have timestamp in string format i.e. "2015-03-24T07:08:24.000Z", how can I convert it back to the timestamp i.e. 2015-03-24T07:08:24.000Z from the given string in ORACLE?

Comment: Use to_timestamp function, follow this link: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions193.htm

Answer (score 2):

Presumably the fixed T and Z are confusing you a bit, as they aren't normal [datetime format model](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00212) elements. But [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#sthref406) says:

> You can include these characters in a date format model:
>
> - Punctuation such as hyphens, slashes, commas, periods, and colons
> - Character literals, enclosed in double quotation marks

So you enclose the T and Z in double-quotes, as `"T"` and `"Z"`, in your format model.

If you aren't interersted in the timezone you can use [the `to_timestamp()` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions213.htm):

```
to_timestamp('2015-03-24T07:08:24.000Z', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3"Z"')
```

Or if you want to have with the timezone you can use [the `to_timestamp_tz()` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions214.htm), which will default to your current session timezone (as you aren't actually specifying one here, the Z isn't interpreted as Zulu/UTC):

```
to_timestamp_tz('2015-03-24T07:08:24.000Z', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3"Z"')
```

If you want it with a timezone and want to specify that it is UTC you can force that with [the `from_tz()` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions068.htm):

```
from_tz(to_timestamp('2015-03-24T07:08:24.000Z', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3"Z"')), 'UTC')
```

To see the difference those produce, specifying a timezone for the session as a demo:

```
alter session set time_zone = 'America/New_York';

select to_timestamp('2015-03-24T07:08:24.000Z', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3"Z"') as no_tz,
  to_timestamp_tz('2015-03-24T07:08:24.000Z', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3"Z"') as default_tz,
  from_tz(to_timestamp('2015-03-24T07:08:24.000Z', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3"Z"'), 'UTC') as utc_tz
from dual;

NO_TZ
--------------------------------------------------
DEFAULT_TZ
--------------------------------------------------
UTC_TZ
--------------------------------------------------
24-MAR-15 07.08.24.000000000                       
24-MAR-15 07.08.24.000000000 AMERICA/NEW_YORK      
24-MAR-15 07.08.24.000000000 UTC
```

I'm assuming the Z is fixed and the values you get are therefore always represent UTC; if you actually get different timezones in the values you need to convert then you'll need to extract and apply those - which is doable, but difficult, and not worth going into unless you actually have that situation.

Comment: Actually the "Z" defines "UTC" - at least according to ISO-8601

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit - yes, hence the third option to force that, which is probably most correct. Maybe I should have been clearer that it should be used though. What I haven't covered is converting that UTC value back to the OP's (session or database) timezone, which I guess should be done if it willl be stored as a timezone without timestamp.