# TO_DATE Recognise date

Tags: oracle, date

Ok, I have this date string:

```
2016-05-31T23:00:00.000Z
```

I want to be able to use it to search on a date in an Oracle 12c table, for example

```
SELECT stuff 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE date_column > TO_DATE('2016-05-31T23:00:00.000Z', 'what goes here?');
```

I can't figure out what format this date is in, can anyone help? This is probably simple, but I can't seem to find it...

Edit: this isn't C#

Comment: do you need the time part?

Comment: Yes, I need the time part.

Comment: @RickRunowski That is `C#` this question tag is `Oracle`

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35379882/266304), if the time needs to be adjusted from UTC ('Z') to the local time. You can also use `TO_DATE()` if the fraction part is always .000, by treating that as a literal too.

Comment: @RickRunowski That appears to be in c#

Comment: @AlexPoole Looks promising... I'm surprised you have to manually put the T & Z in, seems a bit hacky.

Comment: @AlexPoole I do need it in local time, doing this: to_date('2016-05-31T23:00:00.000Z', 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss."000Z"') returns UTC still though?

Comment: It depends if that string is supposed to represent UTC (which the Z implies) or is already in your local time. If the former, the `from_tz()` option makes that expicit, and you can then convert to your local timezone with `at time zone`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need the string representing UTC converted to your local time zone then you need to do a few steps. The starting point is to use `to_timestamp()` with character literals for the T and Z, which Oracle doesn't recognise:

```
select to_timestamp('2016-05-31T23:00:00.000Z', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3"Z"')
from dual;

TO_TIMESTAMP('2016-05-31T23:00:00.000Z','YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3"Z"')
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
2016-05-31 23:00:00.000
```

Then you can state that timezone-less value is actually UTC with `from_tz()`:

```
select from_tz(
  to_timestamp('2016-05-31T23:00:00.000Z', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3"Z"'),
  'UTC')
from dual;

FROM_TZ(TO_TIMESTAMP('2016-05-31T23:00:00.000Z','YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3"Z"'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2016-05-31 23:00:00.000 UTC
```

Then you can convert it to your own time zone:

```
select from_tz(
  to_timestamp('2016-05-31T23:00:00.000Z', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3"Z"'),
  'UTC') at time zone 'Europe/London'
from dual;

FROM_TZ(TO_TIMESTAMP('2016-05-31T23:00:00.000Z','YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3"Z"'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2016-06-01 00:00:00.000 EUROPE/LONDON
```

If you want it back as a date datatype you can cast it:

```
select cast(from_tz(
  to_timestamp('2016-05-31T23:00:00.000Z', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3"Z"'),
  'UTC') at time zone 'Europe/London' as date)
from dual;

CAST(FROM_TZ(TO_TIMESTAMP('2016-05-31T23:00:00.000Z','YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2016-06-01 00:00:00
```

Comment: This looks like it will do the trick - seems convoluted, but thank you for your time. I've just figured out Bash is a lot more forgiving so I'll convert it there first:  `date -d "2016-05-31T23:00:00.000Z"`