# Oracle SQL - How to format date like 2020-06-03T17:39:26Z to a date using to_date

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to convert date strings in a format like this `2020-06-03T17:39:26Z` to dates in Oracle SQL using to_date. I tried `to_date('2020-06-03T17:39:26Z', 'yyyy-mm-ddThh24:mi:ssZ')` but this did not work. What is this date format, there seems to be a lot of questions about it; but no answers for Oracle SQL that I could find? How can I ignore the T and Z or is this important in some way? Basically how can I convert this to a date?

Comment: Try `to_date('2020-06-03T17:39:26Z', 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss"Z"')`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37861985/266304

Comment: The Z is important because it indicates UTC (Zulu). You may, or may not. need to convert to a different time zone.

Comment: Zulus have their own UTC?

Comment: So T and Z stands for Time and Zone? And UTC is also known as Zulu time. Or Z stands for Zulu time as in UTC time?

Comment: Z stands for Zulu, [which is essentially UTC](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/z).  The T is a delimiter between the date and time parts. [Read more about ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

T and Z in the data value will violate the type conversion, you need to format it with double quotes,

```
select to_date('2020-06-03T17:39:26Z', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS"Z"') from dual;
```

You can also use substring to fetch the data value and convert it,

```
select to_date(substr('2020-06-03T17:39:26Z', 0, 10), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') from dual;
```

If you need in timestamp, please use below

```
select to_date(substr('2020-06-03T17:39:26Z', 0, 10)||substr('2020-06-03T17:39:26Z', instr('2020-06-03T17:39:26Z', 'T')+1,8), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') from dual;
```