# How to convert the raw date into standard date format in Oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle, date, sql-date-functions

In Oracle I have date in the format like 2018-06-02T17:31:55.461Z  in varchar field. How do i convert this to standard date field in Oracle db?

```
create table testmp1
(raw_date varchar2(4000));

insert into testmp1
(raw_date) 
values ('2018-06-02T17:31:55.461Z');

insert into testmp1
(raw_date) 
values ('2018-06-02T17:32:48.042Z');

insert into testmp1
(raw_date) 
values ('2015-04-29T19:51:30.0Z');

commit; 

create table testmp2
(new_date date);
```

Comment: Really covert to a date, or to a timestamp, with or without time zone? What do you want to happen to the fractional seconds, and the timezone; is it always Z (UTC)? [This may be what you need?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35380140/266304)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you appear to have are standard JavaScript timestamps. In this case what you'll want to do is convert them to Oracle `TIMESTAMP` values, then possibly to Oracle `DATE` values.

The format mask to convert the text to a `TIMESTAMP` would be the following:

```
YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3"Z"
```

The `T` and `Z` are enclosed in double quotes `"`; they are extraneous to Oracle and not needed at all. You use `FF3` to get the fractional seconds since there are 3 digits of precision. Wrapping this all up, you get:

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP(raw_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3"Z"')
  FROM testmp1;
```

and:

```
INSERT INTO testmp2
  ( new_date )
SELECT CAST(TO_TIMESTAMP(raw_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3"Z"') AS DATE)
  FROM testmp1;
```

EDIT: @Egret's comment below made me think about time zones. The `Z` in the timestamp indicates a zero offset or UTC time; to convert it to your local time, you'll want to do something like this:

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP(raw_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3"Z"') - (SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
  FROM testmp1;
```

and if converting to a `DATE`:

```
SELECT CAST(TO_TIMESTAMP(raw_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3"Z"') - (SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS DATE)
  FROM testmp1;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nice explanation - note that this assumes current timezone

Comment: I believe the `Z` indicates a zero offset or UTC time

Comment: As I posted [on the duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28210331/oracle-sql-query-statement-and-conditions-with-timestamps-and-iso-dates#comment70348874_28211019), use `TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ( raw_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FFTZH:TZM' )` and if you want to convert it to the local time then `CAST( TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ( raw_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FFTZH:TZM' ) AT LOCAL AS DATE )`

Comment: I missed that - thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Split the string in date and time and then convert it to a date, for example:

```
select to_date(substr('2015-04-29T19:51:30.0Z', 1, 10) ||
    substr('2015-04-29T19:51:30.0Z', 12, 8),
    'YYYY-MM-DDHH24:MI:SS')  from dual;
```

This gives you a date. It assumes that the timezone is always the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
select cast(to_timestamp(raw_date,'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.ff3"Z"') as DATE) from testmp1;

insert into testmp2 (new_date) (select cast(to_timestamp(raw_date,'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.ff3"Z"') as DATE) from testmp1);
commit;
```

Answer (score -1):

may be you need to convert

```
 (TO_DATE('2015-04-29T19:51:30.0Z', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'));
```

Comment: What about the T and the Z; and the fractional seconds?